# Delete row if duplicate on more than a col

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code:

```
Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

The problem is that if at least 1 duplicate is found it deletes the entire row.

I need something like this:

```
If (duplicate is found on on columns A & C) then delete entire row
```

I mean delete the row where columns A has duplicates of above/below rows on it and also column C contains duplicates of above/below rows.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: @Sid thats not an obvious solution, and would warrant an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever in doubt, record a macro. To record a macro you may want to see [Automate tasks with the Macro Recorder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b)

When you are recording a macro, do this...

1. Select your range
2. Click on `Data | Remove Duplicates`.
3. In remove duplicates dialog box, Click on `Unselect all` button.
4. Click on Col A and Col C
5. Click Ok

You will get a code which is something like this

```
YourRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 3), Header:=xlNo
```